# Contacting MyHeritage users without premium account

Tags: myheritage.com

Does anybody knows a trick of how to contact other users of MyHeritage if I am not using a premium account? Just purchasing the premium account for an email contact is an overkill for me.

Comment: I haven't paid MH any money and have successfully used their internal messaging system to contact several DNA matches. I haven't a clue whether this applies in the non-DNA parts of the website, though, hence comment rather than answer.

Comment: In case this comforts you :) - I believe this is an overkill for EVERY user. And if not for every... for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this (and have succeeded) twice so far. What I did was looking for the tree admins on Facebook and in general on the internet, trying to find their other accounts that I can reach. It worked in both cases.

Comment: Unluckily the admin has a very common name....

Comment: Then you can also try finding one of the close young relatives from the family tree. Pay attention to Facebook "friends". But in general I agree, it's a poor situation. That's why I decided not to use MyHeritage for my family tree data.

Comment: Always do the same, but as already mentioned, will not always work.